# Unable to connect two tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling

I want to generate a relationship between two tables AW_custmer_Lookup and AW_Returns in Data Maodelng view of POWER BI but unable to create it, is there any way I can connect these two table as I want to display the data of return produts based on customer name in my Report view. The tables are highlighted in the screenshot attached below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands you can't connect it, because from the Returns you don't even know to which specific sale you are returning the item from (you only have product and territory, and there can be many different sales with those pairs), so you'd need at least a link to sale (saleKey) or to customer.

It would be great if you could change your model and "merge" `AW_Sales` with `AW_Returns` (I assume there is no return without a sale, so the sales table could have just a "Return Qty" and a "Return Date" fields and probably both productKey and territoryKey are the same). It would make your model simpler.